# Split sentences into sub-sentences using a recursive PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, split, postgresql-9.1, recursive-query, sentence

Looking for an elegant way in **PostgreSQL** to **split sentences** contained in a table into sub-sentences, assuming that the delimiter is ' '. I would like to use a **recursive query** (like [here](http://technobytz.com/recursive-query-evaluation-postgresql.html)) but I can't build it. Can someone help?

I have the following table:

```
id1 | yes we can
id2 | beautiful mind
id3 | birds can fly
```

and I want like to get something like this:

```
id1 | yes we can
id1 | yes
id1 | we
id1 | can
id1 | yes we
id1 | we can
id2 | beautiful mind
id2 | beautiful
id2 | mind
id3 | birds can fly
id3 | birds can
id3 | can fly
```

A tutorial is accessible [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: The functions you need are: To normalize the compound strings `generate_subscripts()` ,  `string_to_array()` ,  `unnest()` (before the recursive query, which will yield arrays), and to rebuild the strings from the parts: `array_to_string()` after the recursive query.

Comment: Hi joop. Thanks for your help! Do you think you could write the query for me (based on my example)?

Comment: I already wrote it. But I won't do your homework for you. First show us some effort. ( I looked up the functions for you ...)

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450 gives me a clue too. Joop, thanks for your help. I will think about it and come back next week :-)

Comment: `SELECT id
        , generate_subscripts(string_to_array(elements, ','),1) AS seq
        , unnest(string_to_array(elements, ',')) AS elem
FROM myTable
ORDER BY id,seq
        ;` is an easy solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450